# How can I reset this tic-tac-toe gameboard for a new round?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, tic-tac-toe

I have created a multiplayer tic-tac-toe game where a player selects either 'Player One' or 'Player Two' to begin the game. On selecting either 'Player One' or 'Player Two', a placeMark() function is invoked and the chosenPlayer variable is updated, accordingly; this function is responsible for populating an array 'board = Gameboard.gameboard'.

The populated array consists of nine symbols 'x' and 'o' that the allow the player(s) to play the symbols to the divs on the screen via click events. Furthermore, these symbols are then added to the 2-dimensional array, 'game'. Then, the getWinner() function is invoked when the symbols in the 2D array, 'game', score a match accordingly. When that happens getModal() triggers a popup/modal and a replay button.

The replayGame() function is invoked when the 'replay' button is clicked, it correctly clears the divs of their innerHTML, reactives cursor pointer, clears the 2D array for a fresh round, and removes the modal from the screen.

Getting to make the 'replayGame()' function to re-invoke the 'placeMark()' function is where my problem lies; in that function,  I want to re-invoke the placeMark function when the 'replay' button is selected. This is so as to start a new round.

I want to effectively stop the placeMark function from choosing symbols from the 'board' array in its current state, and start the selection of symbols from the beginning of the array. Currently, each time a player wins and I click the 'replay' button, the placeMark function still selects the symbols in the 'board' array from where it left off initially. How can I fix this?

I've tried resetting the 'board' array and re-invoking the placeMark function based-on the player selected, but it still does not work.

```js
const GameBoard = (() => {
  let gameboard = [];
  return {
    gameboard
  };

})();

const players = (() => {
  const player1 = {
    name: '',
    sign: "x"
  };
  const player2 = {
    name: '',
    sign: "o"
  };
  let one = player1.sign;
  let two = player2.sign;
  return {
    one,
    two
  };

})();


const gameflow = (() => {
  let board = GameBoard.gameboard;
  let one = document.getElementById('one')
  let two = document.getElementById('two');
  let cells = document.getElementsByClassName('cells');
  let array = Array.from(cells);
  let game = [
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', ''],
    ['', '', '']
  ];
  let value = '';
  let chosenPlayer = "";

  const addSymbol = (row, col, sign) => {
    if (game[row][col] === '') {
      game[row][col] = sign;
    }
  }



  const getWinner = (...sign) => {
    // HORIZONTAL
    // PLAYER X
    if (sign[0] === game[0][0] && sign[0] === game[0][1] && sign[0] === game[0][2]) {
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    if (sign[0] === game[1][0] && sign[0] === game[1][1] && sign[0] === game[1][2]) {
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    if (sign[0] === game[2][0] && sign[0] === game[2][1] && sign[0] === game[2][2]) {
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }

    // PLAYER O
    if (sign[1] === game[0][0] && sign[1] === game[0][1] && sign[1] === game[0][2]) {
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }

    if (sign[1] === game[1][0] && sign[1] === game[1][1] && sign[1] === game[1][2]) {
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    if (sign[1] === game[2][0] && sign[1] === game[2][1] && sign[1] === game[2][2]) {
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }

    /* Vertical */
    // PLAYER X
    if (sign[0] === game[0][0] && sign[0] === game[1][0] && sign[0] === game[2][0]) {;
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    if (sign[0] === game[0][1] && sign[0] === game[1][1] && sign[0] === game[2][1]) {;
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;


    }
    if (sign[0] === game[0][2] && sign[0] === game[1][2] && sign[0] === game[2][2]) {;
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    // PLAYER O
    if (sign[1] === game[0][0] && sign[1] === game[1][0] && sign[1] === game[2][0]) {
      getPopup(players.nameO);
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    if (sign[1] === game[0][1] && sign[1] === game[1][1] && sign[1] === game[2][1]) {
      getPopup(players.nameO);
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;

    }
    if (sign[1] === game[0][2] && sign[1] === game[1][2] && sign[1] === game[2][2]) {
      getPopup(players.nameO);
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;


    }

    /* Diagonally */
    // PLAYER X
    if (sign[0] === game[0][0] && sign[0] === game[1][1] && sign[0] === game[2][2]) {;
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;


    }

    if (sign[0] === game[0][2] && sign[0] === game[1][1] && sign[0] === game[2][0]) {;
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;


    }

    // PLAYER O
    if (sign[1] === game[0][0] && sign[1] === game[1][1] && sign[1] === game[2][2]) {
      getPopup(players.nameO);
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;


    }
    if (sign[1] === game[0][2] && sign[1] === game[1][1] && sign[1] === game[2][0]) {
      getPopup(players.nameO);
      stopClick();
      toggleModal();
      value = true;






    }


  }


  const replayGame = () => {
    const modalWrapper = document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper');
    const replay = document.getElementById('replay');
    replay.addEventListener('click', () => {
      modalWrapper.style.display = "none";
      array.forEach(cell => {
        cell.innerHTML = "";
      });
      array.forEach(cell => {
        cell.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';

      });
      for (let i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < game.length; j++) {
          game[i][j] = "";
        }


      }

      // reset the board
      board.length = 0;

      if (chosenPlayer === "x") {
        placeMark(players.one);

      }
      if (chosenPlayer === "o") {
        placeMark(players.two);
      }



    });

  }





  const placeMark = (sign) => {
    let i = 0;

    if (sign === players.one) {
      let x = "x";
      let o = "o";
      let values = [x, o];


      while (board.length < 9) {
        board.push(values[board.length % 2]);
      }
    } else if (sign === players.two) {
      let x = "x";
      let o = "o";
      let values = [o, x];


      while (board.length < 9) {
        board.push(values[board.length % 2]);
      }

    }

    array.forEach(cell => {
      cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (cell.innerHTML === "") {
          cell.innerHTML = board[i++];
          let strings = cell.id;
          let one = parseInt(strings.charAt(0));
          let two = parseInt(strings.charAt(1));
          addSymbol(one, two, cell.innerHTML);
          getWinner(players.one, players.two);
          checkTie();







        }

      })
    });







  }


  const choosePlayer = () => {
    one.addEventListener('click', () => {
      chosenPlayer = "x";
      placeMark(players.one);

    })
    two.addEventListener('click', () => {

      placeMark(players.two);
      chosenPlayer = "o";

    });




  }

  const stopClick = () => {
    array.forEach(cell => {
      cell.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    })
  }

  const checkTie = () => {
    let one = game[0].every(checkArray);
    let two = game[1].every(checkArray);
    let three = game[2].every(checkArray);
    if (one === true && two === true && three === true && value !== true) {
      document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = "Tie Game!";
    }

    function checkArray(element) {
      return element !== "";

    }
  }



  const toggleModal = () => {
    const modalWrapper = document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper');
    modalWrapper.style.display = "flex";

  }

  choosePlayer();





  return {
    replayGame
  };






})();


gameflow.replayGame();
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.container-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 750px;
}

.container-outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 750px;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 80px 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-button {
  background: #e20540;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.cells {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-outer">
  <header>
    <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="players">
    <button type="button" id="one">Player One</button>
    <button type="button" id="two">Player Two</button>
  </div>



  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="cell-1 cells" id="00" data-index="0"></div>
    <div class="cell-2 cells" id="01" data-index="1"></div>
    <div class="cell-3 cells" id="02" data-index="2"></div>
    <div class="cell-4 cells" id="10" data-index="3"></div>
    <div class="cell-5 cells" id="11" data-index="4"></div>
    <div class="cell-6 cells" id="12" data-index="5"></div>
    <div class="cell-7 cells" id="20" data-index="6"></div>
    <div class="cell-8 cells" id="21" data-index="7"></div>
    <div class="cell-9 cells" id="22" data-index="8"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="popup"></div>
      <button type="button" id="replay">Replay</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Because it was escaped. That's a lot of code/etc to dig through to try to find a nebulous problem.

Comment: @trincot can you please look into it now? I have inserted runnable code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? After a completed game, should it be as it was at the start where one of the two player buttons must be clicked first before the game starts, or do you want the same player to start the next game as the one that started the previous game?

Comment: @trincot After a completed game, I want the same player to start the next game.

Comment: The function `getPop` is called but not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this code:

```
  array.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (cell.innerHTML === "") {
        cell.innerHTML = board[i++];
        let strings = cell.id;
        let one = parseInt(strings.charAt(0));
        let two = parseInt(strings.charAt(1));
        addSymbol(one, two, cell.innerHTML);
        getWinner(players.one, players.two);
        checkTie();
      }
    })
  });
```

This block of code is executed *again* when a new game starts. This is problematic:

- This means each cell will get an *additional* click handler that executes when the user clicks.
- These click handlers use a variable `i` that is local to an execution instance of `replayGame`, and so it is a different variable each time `replayGame` executes.

You should only execute that block of code once, and instead of using a variable `i`, you can just shift the next symbol out of the `board` array, using the the `shift` method.

So place this code outside of the `replayGame` function, somewhere after you have defined the `array` variable, at the same level, and use `shift`:

```
  array.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (cell.innerHTML === "") {
        cell.innerHTML = board.shift() // <----
        let strings = cell.id;
        let one = parseInt(strings.charAt(0));
        let two = parseInt(strings.charAt(1));
        addSymbol(one, two, cell.innerHTML);
        getWinner(players.one, players.two);
        checkTie();
      }
    })
  });
```

This will solve the problem you asked about. There are several other issues. For instance when the game is a draw, the popup is not displayed and so there is no way to start a new game. Also, the `players` function creates objects with name properties, but those objects are lost as you only return the `sign` properties. You should look into such things...

#### Other remarks

I would suggest you rewrite the program, and take these considerations in mind:

- Avoid repetition of code. Examples of such repetitions:

  - `while (board.length < 9)`
  - `toggleModal();`
- Separate code that deals with *presentation* (HTML in this case) from the code that deals with the game *logic*. For example, a function that check for a win (`getWinner`) should not itself interact with the HTML page (for example with `toggleModal`). This should be separated in two functions.
- Avoid global variables as much as possible. You could have global variables for referencing HTML elements and one object-variable for representing the game state. That should be it. So for example, maintain `chosenPlayer` and `value` as *properties* of the `GameBoard` object. Use either `cells` or `array`, but not both. Etc.